# Losing typical Computer Modern typical curved x glyphe

Tags: latex

How to avoid losing typical Computer Modern typical curved "x" glyphe in math modes, when switching for \sfdefault for the whole document ?

```
%%% not canonical minimal.tex sample %%%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}

Je compose avec Babel pour la langue française, avec deux contraintes: police sans empattement, et véritable virgule française conforme aux usages pour les nombres à virgule.

Voici un document minimal, où je perds le $x$ arrondi habituel en Computer Modern. Je vérifie ce que donne la macro \verb+\num{}+ avec  \num{5.2} et $\num{5.2}$ et \SI{5.2}{\kilo\metre\squared}.
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f\!\left( x \right) dx = \num{5.2} \quad \text{où} \quad AB = 5.2
$$

Le $x$ ne me convient pas (confusion pour certains élèves).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows us which documentclass and packages you use?

Comment: Commenting `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}`, you will get sans serif text and the default font for all math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @UlrikeFischer's solution at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57560730#57560730 you can use the following code to get the curly x back:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
%
\DeclareSymbolFont{myletters}{T1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSymbol{x}\mathalpha{myletters}{"78}}
\MTmathstandardletters
\begin{document}

Je compose avec Babel pour la langue française, avec deux contraintes: police sans empattement, et véritable virgule française conforme aux usages pour les nombres à virgule.

Voici un document minimal, où je perds le $x$ arrondi habituel en Computer Modern. Je vérifie ce que donne la macro \verb+\num{}+ avec  \num{5.2} et $\num{5.2}$ et \SI{5.2}{\kilo\metre\squared}.
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f\!\left( x \right) dx = \num{5.2} \quad \text{où} \quad AB = 5.2
$$

Le $x$ ne me convient pas (confusion pour certains élèves).

\end{document}
```

[image]